# CSS Vertical Layout with TABLE

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm sorry if this was already answered, but it's kind of difficult to search for something with "100% height".

My problem is that I need 100% height table layout because of automatic cell resizing done by browser, which I don't want to script myself for obvious reasons.

It differs from other "100% problems", in that I need some cells to stick on the top and some on the bottom, and have the middle resized by browser to fill remaining space.

That sort of works, the problem happens when I need that middle part to contain overflowing stuff, and obviously I want overflow:auto there to enable user thru that stuff. It works in WebKit; in Firefox, it doesn't; others not tested. Here's the test case.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        table {
            height: 100%;
            width: 200px;
            border: 0;
        }

        .fill {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .cont {
            overflow: auto;
            height: 100%;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:50px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:100px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fill">
                <div class="cont">
                    An opaque handle to a native JavaScript object. A JavaScriptObject cannot be created directly. JavaScriptObject should be declared as the return type of a JSNI method that returns native (non-Java) objects. A JavaScriptObject passed back into JSNI from Java becomes the original object, and can be accessed in JavaScript as expected
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:100px"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: You say "it doesn't," ... please complete the sentence.

Comment: "in Firefox, it doesn't" its a comma splice. it doesn't work in Firefox but works in WebKit based browsers

Comment: This sounds like a standard header-body-footer layout, no different than the many many such layouts people have worked out using just CSS. (Search for "sticky footer" to get more examples than you can shake a stick at.) Why do you believe you need a table?

Comment: No it's not header/footer problem, the point here is to have middle cell scaled by browser to fill the remaining space, and have an overflowing content there. If you would test that sample in WebKit, you would see how that is supposed to work.

Comment: It is a header/footer issue - the middle of the page can be made to scroll with an 'internal' scrollbar - ie not the page scrollbar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this it works!

I tested it using

- Internet Explorer 7 & 8 (Windows)
- FireFox 3.5
  (Mac & Windows)
- Safari 4.0 (Mac &
  Windows)

Maybe you want to change the width and increase the min-height to a pixel value.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/afava)
[Source](http://jsbin.com/afava/edit)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        table {
            height: 100%;
            width: 200px;
            border: 0;
        }

        .fill {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .cont {
            position:relative;
            max-height:100%;
            min-height:100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .cont2 {
            position:absolute;
            height: 100%;
            overflow:auto;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr style="height:50px">
            <td style="height:50px">50px</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:50px">
            <td style="height:100px">100px</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fill">
                 <div class="cont">
                    <div class="cont2">
                    An opaque handle to a native JavaScript object. A JavaScriptObject cannot be created directly. JavaScriptObject should be declared as the return type of a JSNI method that returns native (non-Java) objects. A JavaScriptObject passed back into JSNI from Java becomes the original object, and can be accessed in JavaScript as expected
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:50px">
            <td style="height:100px">100px</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! Now, it seems that you can also answer, how can I make it done with variable height cells on top/bottom? In other words, I don't know their height, but I can measure them, which is tricky and I would like to avoid that

Comment: Set there height to 1px `height: 1px;`. This might work. Just play with height and min-height.

Comment: Sounds good, that should work, just testing with Strict doctype, and it seems not to work anymore :(

Comment: I can set up new question and bounty again if that can help somehow :)